# wrong parsing of email subject in java using java mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using Java mail 1.4.6 to read and parse emails of gmail inbox. But the problem is when i am tying to parse emaill subject (example subject string is "Build failed in Jenkins: appanalyti​x » appanalyti​x #51") with statement

`String subjectStr=(String) mimeMessage.getSubject();`

I am getting

> subjectStr as "Build failed in Jenkins: appanalytix » appanal" instead
>   "Build failed in Jenkins: appanalyti​x » appanalyti​x #51".

May i know where i am going wrong? Is it needed to decode the Subject string

code is:

```
public boolean parseEmailSubject(String host,String userName,String password,String configurationStringToCheck,String saveDirectory){
....
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        try {
            IMAPSSLStore store = (IMAPSSLStore)session.getStore(IMAP);
            store.connect( host, userName, password ) ;
            Folder folderInbox =store.getFolder(IMAP_FOLDER);
            folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.getMessages();
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayMessages.length; i++) {
                MimeMessage message = (MimeMessage) arrayMessages[i];
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                message.writeTo(bos);
                bos.close();
                SharedByteArrayInputStream bis =new SharedByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
                MimeMessage cmsg = new MimeMessage(session, bis);
                bis.close();

                String megSubject = cmsg.getSubject();
                if(megSubject.contains(configurationStringToCheck)){
                    String contentType = cmsg.getContentType();

                    if (contentType.contains(IMAP_CONTENT_TYPE)) {
                        Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) cmsg.getContent();
                        int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                        for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                            MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                            if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                                String fileName = part.getFileName();
                                part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return true;

                }

            }
            folderInbox.close(false);
            store.close();

        }catch (Exception e) {
        }
}
```

email sample is
(subject line below)
Build failed in Jenkins: appanalyti​x » appanalyti​x #51

(body part below)
Changes:

---

<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>   channel started
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: Can we see your code and an email sample (without any private data)?

Comment: I have edited above to add code and email sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaMail decodes the subject for you.  Of course, if the subject is improperly encoded, it's not going to decode properly.

What's the raw text in the Subject header?

What's the JavaMail debug output show?

Comment: "Build failed in Jenkins: appanalyti​x » appanalyti​x #51". this is my subject contains and output i am getting is  "Build failed in Jenkins: appanalytix » appanal" and when i run junit test case i am getting currect subject content.

Comment: Is that the text you get from [msg.getHeader("Subject", null)](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getHeader(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))?  Again, what's the debug output show?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using gmail server then this is the best code just enter your user name and password and run it

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "username";
        final String password = "fghdf";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("username"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("to email is"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear user ,"
                + "\n\n your username is xxx and pasword is yyy");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```